# Windows Registry Strings and Keys…what do they mean?

Tags: windows, windows-registry

I want to add custom folders to Windows 10 Pro x64 Control Panel, This PC and Navigation Pane. I found several tutorials (tenforums and winaero) that offer pre-made registry scripts to add applets and folders to control panel and file explorer. However, I would like to know more about what some of the strings and keys in HKCR\Classes\CSLID mean, what they do, and how to properly choose the right values. I am not a coder/programmer and the MS documentation is a bit unintuitive and unclear.

For example, say I want to add back the old Notification Area Icons applet back to control panel. The GUID is {05d7b0f4-2121-4eff-bf6b-ed3f69b894d9}. Some questions about the registry entry:

1. System.Software.TasksFileUrl="Internal"
2. InProcServer32=%SystemRoot%\System32\shdocvw.dll and ThreadingModel=Apartment
3. Instance
4. InitPropertyBag, ResourceDLL=taskbarcpl.dll and ResourceID=dword:00000064
5. ShellFolder, Attributes=dword:a0000000 and WantsParseDisplayName=""

What do the keys, strings and values mean, what do they do and how do you know what values to assign?

Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to get exact explanation for each string but in Microsoft Documents, there are some examples, which might give some clues:How to Register Executable Control Panel Items and Integrate a Cloud Storage Provider
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh127450(v=vs.85)
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/integrate-cloud-storage

Answer (score 1):

Let me start by saying you never have to change these settings manually. You can but that doesn't mean you should. To your question **"how to properly choose the right values."** the answer is **"let the software do it for you. Don't change these settings."**

Only Microsoft engineers know what Windows registry keys mean. Unfortunately, they don't maintain a public reference of all settings. There are undocumented registry settings that come out through Microsoft employees or hackers who try things and reverse engineer settings.

This is what Microsoft says about CLSID:

```
A CLSID is a globally unique identifier that identifies a COM class object.
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/clsid-key-hklm?redirectedfrom=MSDN

So that's any COM object. Not only parts of Windows but any application that registers a COM object with the system. Obviously, Microsoft isn't responsible for COM objects written by 3rd parties but it would be nice if they documented their own.

**InProcServer32** defines the DLL that contains the COM object.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/inprocserver32

For more information about this COM object you would then have to look up the reference for that DLL. Your DLL is "Shell Doc Object and Control Library".

Here is an example of a time when Nirsoft was collecting information about all the DLL files in Windows XP:
https://xpdll.nirsoft.net/shdocvw_dll.html

#5 tells us that the item is a `ShellFolder`. Here is some information on ShellFolders:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder